# How to run a Validation Error in clean funtion using django query?

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class Stockdata(models.Model):
    company     = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Company_stock')
    quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    rate        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    opening     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    stock_name  = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I want to make the `stock_name` unique for every `company`.
So, I have done the following:

```
def clean(self):
    if Stockdata.objects.filter(company=self.company,stock_name__iexact=self.stock_name).exists():
        raise ValidationError({'stock_name':["This stock name already exists"]})
```

But when I try to `save()` or `submit` the form it creates a duplicate value(i.e. it creates a value which already exists in the same company).

Any idea how to perform this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def clean_stock_name(self):
    stock_name = self.cleaned_data['stock_name']

    if Stockdata.objects.filter(company=self.company,stock_name__iexact=stock_name).exists():
        raise ValidationError({'stock_name':["This stock name already exists"]})
    return stock_name
```

hope it helps

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: I am getting this error now `The argument field must be None when the error argument contains errors for multiple fields.`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a [composed unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) instead:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('company', 'stock_name'), )
```

Also, from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

> Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.

So, you have to call it manually. Which can be "automated" by adding custom mixin or a base class with a functionality like below:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.full_clean()
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How do I raise a error message if it is not unique.I want to show the users an error message.

Comment: `unique_together` will do all the work for you. If you don't want it - see the code sample and the link to docs about clean method.

Comment: I don't understand where and how you're receiving 404.

Comment: Actually its redirecting me to a error page and giving me the `error` message when debug is set to `False`. I want to display the `Validation error` message in the same form.

Comment: What is redirecting you? `unique_together` has nothing to do with redirects. Please update your question with modified code and the error message text.